# Color the cells in DataGrid based on TextBox value without converters

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a TextBox and a datagrid. I need to change the backgorund color of the cells from the column 'Omschrijving' inside de datagrid which have the similar value as the TextBox has.

I can't use any custom converter class for this issue. So I need to solve this with XAML codes or in the page's class only.

**Example code:**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTrefwoord"/>

<DataGrid x:Name="gridFiche" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Omschrijving}" Header="Omschrijving" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>                    
</DataGrid>
```

**An example screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If the rationale of determining the color according to the text is simple (like your example - two kinds of texts), you can use a trigger, that if the text is "..." set the Background as "...".

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Omschrijving}" Header="Omschrijving" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtTrefwoord, Path=Text}" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text }" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger><!--not sure that's the path-->
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Something like that. writing it from my head, without checking it.

Comment: @KorkiKorkig Added it in my answer.

Comment: sorry it didn't work with DataTrigger; `A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DataTrigger'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a...`

Comment: That's true. For this you need to use MultiBinding, which requires a Converter, and you don't want it. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: downvoiting to make it visible for other users here.